# Link to column entry from org-mode text

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I would like to reference a specific table entry, or have it's value insert inline in an Org document. My motivation is to avoid having to change the text in case I recompute values. Dummy example:

```
#+name: table
|  Metric          | Value  |
|------------------+--------|
|  current         | 152.2  |
|  avg-to-date     | 130.3  |
```

As we see in [[table][this table]], the current value of something is *link-to-value-within-table*.

Is there a way to achieve that?